# How do I wait for a <ul> element to change because of an input search, given that if there are no results the ul is hidden?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, specflow

### How do I wait for a **< ul >** element to change because of an **< input >** search, given that if there are no results the **< ul >** is hidden?

- I have tried *implicitWait* and *pageLoad* methods, but those don't work in this case, since what I need is an element specific wait (the page and its elements already loaded).
- Also, waiting for the specific `<ul>` element to show up is useless as well, since it is already present before I type the search.
- I also can't use as criteria the resulting `<li>` elements to verify the search , for mainly two reasons: that is what I am verifying on the next step of the test; *javascript* hides the `<ul>` if there are no results for that search.

What I need is some kind of method that waits for the `<ul>` to refresh/change, but I am not sure if that exists or even makes sense.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is that element get refreshed or only some attribute is changed? There are expected conditions for both cases.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the HTML for the list in two different states: 1) when the list has no results; 2) the list when it has the results you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this shortly after I posted but I just remembered to give give the answer later, for those interested. There was an element (a spinner) that appeared while the search (the ul) was loading, and by freezing the page using dev tools, I managed to locate that spinner element. Then I only had to wait for it to disappear using SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions. Thanks for the help anyways!

Answer (score 0):

There are expected conditions for both these states.
For the case element is refreshed you can use.

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf(element));
```

For element attribute changed you can use

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.attributeContains(element, attribute, expectedValue));
```